How do we secure firebase storage storageBucket URL from being exposed online? Environment variables are not working for firebaseConfig?
How do we set up apiKey and storageBucket in environment url for firebaseConfig? I have tried using environment variable but it throws error for no bucket url set up before initializing app. I tried clearing .next folder and recompiled but still same error. Without securing storageBucket url, it is exposed to be added by anyone as the apiKey is also not being read from firebase storage. How to configure firebase storage from firebase security rules, so that user can upload only with valid API key from my .env file. I searched internet and also took help of chatGPT but did not find relevant answer. I'm working with NextJS 14.2.3.
firebase configuration provided by firebase.
/firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


/.env

FIREBASE = firebase-api-string
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN = auth-domain-string
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = project-id-string
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET = storage-bucket-string
FIREBASE_SENDER_ID = sender-id-string
FIREBASE_APP_ID = app-id-string


/page.js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { app } from '@/utils/firebase';

const storage = getStorage(app);

    const upload = () => {
      const name = new Date().getTime();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, name + file.name);

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case 'paused':
              console.log('Upload is paused');
              break;
            case 'running':
              console.log('Upload is running');
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.code);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            console.log(downloadURL);
            setMedia(downloadURL);
          });
        }
      );
    };

    file && upload();


But this doesn't work by taking storageBucket into environment variable .env file. I want to configure such that I my storageBucket url is not exposed to public. Also, it is not validating apiKey from firebase storage rule.
/firebase
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 200 * 1024 && request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

I have recently started with backend development and I'm not able to understand firebase documentation accurately. If there is better resource to learn these things, please help me to reach that. TIA.

"I want to configure such that I my storageBucket url is not exposed to public." If you want to allow uploads to Cloud Storage directly from the client, that client will have to know the storage bucket URL. There's no way to upload without it. Same for the API key: that is also just necessary configuration data for Firebase to work, and not a security mechanism. --- The proper way to secure this is through security rules (which you're already looking at) and possibly App Check. --- Have a look at the question I linked for more on this.
